# Circular reference of two class objects in C++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to achieve this code?

```
class apple;
class fruit{
    public: int i;
    void set(apple a){
    }
};

class apple{
    public: int j;
    void set(fruit f){
    }
};
```

I know this leads to error: 'a' has incomplete type. even I interchange classes, It always leads to incomplete type error. I have a question can this be achieved? Iam not sure. any help is greatly apprciated. Thanks

**Update**

```
class apple;
class fruit{
    public: int i;
    void set(apple* a);
};

class apple{
    public: int j;
    void set(fruit f){
    }
};
void fruit::set(apple *a){
  apple b = *a;
}
```

I Guess this workaround works. but is there any other solution?

Comment: Judging by the names of your classes are you sure that's what you want? It seems like `fruit` should be the base class of `apple`, in other words `class apple : public fruit`

Comment: @Cyber Im trying to learn concepts, its not the real code. that uses inheritance.

Comment: Why do you get incompatible type? You have declared the classes in separate files? Otherwise keep them in order. You have defined class apple after fruit. Also, you seems to be getting confused towards your way to achieve an inheritence hierarchy of fruit and apple.

Comment: @hagubear Yes but it requires complete type even when you specify forward declarion of class.

Comment: No, there isn't another solution. You should get used to writing functions non-inline. If you ever work on a non-trivial project, you'll find it essential to avoid both this kind of circular dependency and long build times.

Comment: "is there any other solution?" - no, declaring each class before use is the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, but you need to have method definitions outside of the class:

```
class apple;

class fruit {
public:
    int i;
    void set(apple a);
};

class apple {
public:
    int j;
    void set(fruit f);
};

void fruit::set(apple a)
{
    i = a.j;
}
void apple::set(fruit f)
{
    j = f.i;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I have understood :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using pointers or references, since only the name needs to be known in that case:

```
class apple;

class fruit{
    public: 
    int i;
    void set(apple* a); // OK
    void set(apple& a); // Also OK
};
```

And you need to move the implementation of the function to a place where the definition of `apple` is known.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a circular reference like this. Only possibility is to have a pointer to object used instead of object, as in:

```
class apple;
class fruit{
    public: int i;
    void set(apple * a){
    }
};

class apple{
    public: int j;
    void set(fruit * f){
    }
};
```

and manage with de-referenced object within the functions, i.e. use *f within the implementation of these functions `apple::set` and `fruit::set`
If you would like to have the object non-modifiable when you pass as a pointer, use as:

```
class apple;
class fruit{
    public: int i;
    void set(const apple * a){
    }
};

class apple{
    public: int j;
    void set(const fruit * f){
    }
};
```

Comment: But derefercing it modifies actualy value. fruit->i = 2;  modifies the passed object.

Comment: you may then pass as: void apple::set(const fruit * f)